# For loop does not work with Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/) in Wordpress to write php in a page but every time I use a for loop it gives me this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ';'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You need to show some code for us to help. What is the PHP you are trying to include?

Comment: Just a simple for loop. It works outside of wordpress, and I used other loops aswell. 
But it does works with other plugins, so it's fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin ***does not work with loops***. It is a known issue if you take a look at the reviews.
There is a plugin that I often use and that works perfectly. It is called `WP-exec PHP`.

**Link here**: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-exec-php/